# Dragging on canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag, mousemove, mousedown

I've been using the `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and other touch events, but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

My goal is to try to get an object that follows the user's finger or mouse. I tried using mousemove, and it worked, but only on the computer. On a mobile device it failed, only following the beginning of the tap, and nothing else.

I think the problem might be caused because on a computer, if the mouse is clicked and dragged, the computer perceives it as a drag. On mobile, a drag might mean you are not done with the tap.

Any ideas on what to use, or what the problem is?

Thank you in advance!

Here's some example code

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
});
```

Comment: We need to see your code to help.

Comment: @Feathercrown I am on a mobile device so the code looks unformatted but that's the jist of it. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For touchscreen input, you will have to use the [touch-event API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).
These API includes

- touchstart
- touchend
- touchcancel
- touchmove

Alternatively, if you can experiment with the new [pointer event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) APIs.
With that you can write code similar with using mouse's event. e.g.

- mousedown > pointerdown
- mouseup > pointerup
- mousemove > pointermove

> This specification integrates various inputs from mice, touchscreens, and pens, making separate implementations no longer necessary and authoring for cross-device pointers easier. Not to be mistaken with the unrelated "pointer-events" CSS property. -- caniuse

However, it is not well supported by other browser yet. See [pointer's browsers compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer)

Fortunately, there is a polyfill for that https://github.com/jquery/PEP